# Multi Api call using redux and thunk doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-router, redux-thunk

I want to use redux to call API in react native. Redux is ok when I want to call only single API in a component but when I want to dispatch more than one API. it just mix up and i can not handle in `componentWillRecieveProps`.
this is my component which I want to call API in it:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Alert,View,Text,Button } from 'react-native';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';
import { generateOTP,getAnother } from '../Actions'
class Splash extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onPress=this.onPress.bind(this);
    this.onClick=this.onClick.bind(this);
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {

    if (nextProps !== this.props) {
      if( nextProps.api.status === 'api_success' && nextProps.api.error===null) {
        Alert.alert("yes successfully take data");
      }
      if(nextProps.myApp.status === 'success' && nextProps.myApp.error === null){
        Alert.alert("you call second api");
      }
    }
  }
  onClick(){
    this.props.dispatch(getAnother());
  }
  onPress(){
    this.props.dispatch(generateOTP());
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <View>
          <Button  title="Click me first" onPress={this.onPress}/>
          <Text>Extraa space</Text>
          <Text>Extraa space</Text>
          <Button title="Click me" onPress={this.onClick}/>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(state => state)(Splash)
```

To tell you exactly when i click on Click me button both condition inside this if (nextProps !== this.props) block will be true and trigger Alert to me.
api-reducer.js:

```
const initialState = {
    data: {},
    error: null,
    status: null
};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "GENERATE_OTP_PENDING":
            // Action is pending (request is in progress)
            return {...state, status: 'fetching'}
        case "GENERATE_OTP_FULFILLED":
            // Action is fulfilled (request is successful/promise resolved)
            return {
                ...state,
                error: null,
                data: action.payload.data,
                status: 'api_success'
            }
        case "GENERATE_OTP_REJECTED":
            // Action is rejected (request failed/promise rejected)
            return {
                ...state,
                error: action.payload,
                status: 'api_error'
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }

};
```

tagreducer.js:

```
const initialState = {
    data: {},
    error: null,
    status: null
};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "GET_INFORMATION_PENDING":
            // Action is pending (request is in progress)
            return {...state, status: 'fetching'}
        case "GET_INFORMATION_FULFILLED":
            // Action is fulfilled (request is successful/promise resolved)
            return {
                ...state,
                error: null,
                data: action.payload.data,
                status: 'success'
            }
        case "GET_INFORMATION_REJECTED":
            // Action is rejected (request failed/promise rejected)
            return {
                ...state,
                error: action.payload,
                status: 'error'
            }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

this is the way I index or combine both recuder:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { routerReducer } from 'react-router-redux';
import api from './api-reducer';
import myApp from './tagreducer';
export default combineReducers({
  api,
  myApp,
  routing: routerReducer,
});
```

The Actions.js:

```
import axios from 'axios';
import * as config from '../Config';

export const generateOTP = () => ({
    type: 'GENERATE_OTP',
    payload: axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
      headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}
    })
});
export const getAnother = () => ({
    type: 'GET_INFORMATION',
    payload: axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: 'https://newsapi.org/v2/sources?apiKey=94da7332cf0a4b1ea685afc9a6829078',
      headers: {"Accept": "application/json"}
    })
});
```

and finally my `Store.js`:

```
import { applyMiddleware, createStore } from 'redux';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import promiseMiddleware from 'redux-promise-middleware';
import logger from 'redux-logger'
import reducers from './Reducers';

export default function configureStore(history) {
  const middleware = applyMiddleware(
    promiseMiddleware(),
    thunk,
    logger,
    routerMiddleware(history));

  return createStore(reducers, {}, middleware);
}
```